# Flutter ImageCrop library camera permission error in iOS version

Tags: ios, flutter

I'm trying to use [ImageCrop](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image_crop#-readme-tab-) library to crop image in a Flutter app. In this library we can ask user to grant permission to access camera by

> final permissionsGranted = await ImageCrop.requestPermissions();

This works well in android and present permission dialog in android but it is not working in iOS. Anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: That permission dialogue is not presenting in iOS ? Have you added permission requests in .plist file in your xcode project?

Comment: @DarshanPatel No. I'm trying that now.

Comment: Do let me know if that permission will not resolve your issue

Comment: Thanks @DarshanPatel. I had to add 'Camera usage Description' and 'Photo Library Usage Description' in order to work this library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you try by adding below permissions in .plist file in XCode.

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>camera description.</string>

<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string> photos description.</string>
```

Hope this work for you.

Answer (score 0):

i think if you want to get permission try to add permissionhandler package , and use it:

```
await PermissionHandler().requestPermissions([PermissionGroup.camera]) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

@Darshan Patel's answer is the correct one. I'm adding few screenshots if anyone face the same problem and worrying how to add those permissions when using Android Studio.

[image]

Open info.plist in Runner package. Add followings inside  tag.

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs to access photo library</string>
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs Camera Usage</string>
```